# How do I get / set product price programmatically?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and trying to make a desktop application which manipulates products and prices (planning to use visual basic).

I've searched the internet a lot however couldn't find a good answer to where the product names and their prices are stored.

Can I manipulate data using php or mysql from desktop?

Comment: All data is saved in mysql database, you just need to find the way how to manipulate mysql from visual basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce stores products in the 'posts' table of the schema. Instead of manually updating the DB, I would use the provided API.

From there, you can let WooCommerce handle all of the nitty gritty of updating products, managing the data structure, etc.

This also allows you to not have updates to WooCommerce break your application if they change their DB layout.

[WooCommerce API v3](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#products)

Comment: I've come across with it however I tought that it was read-only. Anyway I'll go on with this and notify if something goes wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: NP, I would take a long, hard look at VB though. From what I understand, working with REST services can be a real pain with VB.